Why is apostrophe getting escaped?
I have a list of strings that I need to join together. Some of the strings have embedded quotes ("), some have embedded apostrophes ('). When I join them together the result contains backslashes that I cannot get rid of. I'll demonstrate using Python 3.12:
l = [
  'xxx"xxx"xxx',
  "xxx'xxx'xxx"
]
l
# ['xxx"xxx"xxx', "xxx'xxx'xxx"]

When I join them together using commas as separator backslashes are introduced:
", ".join(l)
# 'xxx"xxx"xxx, xxx\'xxx\'xxx'

However, if I only join on the second element, no backslashes are introduced:
", ".join([l[1]])
# "xxx'xxx'xxx"

I need to remove the backslashes from the join() output so I try:
", ".join(l).replace('\\', '')
# 'xxx"xxx"xxx, xxx\'xxx\'xxx'

but the backslashes are still present.
Assuming it's not possible to change the input list, how can I derive the string I need, which is:
'xxx"xxx"xxx, xxx'xxx'xxx'

i.e. no backslashes?

Because 'xxx"xxx"xxx, xxx'xxx'xxx' wouldn't be a valid string literal? Those backslashes aren't in the actual string.

print(", ".join(l))

The backslashes serve only to escape here.

Thx Jon, that makes complete sense. The problem I have is that those values are actual columns in a SQL statement (I used xxx for brevity). When I execute the SQL statement against my database (cursor.execute(sql)) the slashes are still present therefore I get error "Syntax error: unexpected '''. (line 115)". Maybe I should re-post and explain the problem more fully.

You're doing something very wrong with the code that creates your SQL statement then, which is not represented in this question.

@jamiet I would agree. Update this question with the additional details outlining the actual problem you are having with the sql. Sharing your code that builds and executes the sql would probably help.

JNevill, good advice, thank you. And thank you all for the replies.

OK, the mistake I was making was copying/pasting the SQL statement from my debugger into my database query tool. Of course, when I did so the apostrophes are in the SQL statement (for reasons that other folks here have correctly explained). When I execute the SQL statement against the DB (cursor.execute(sql)) it behaves as expected. Apologies folks, realise I was being a bit silly here, wish I'd have rubber-ducked in private rather than in public :)
